# one-to-one tables relationship, linked by the autonumber in the main table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a main table that contain the customers details, I built another table that contain for example a yes/no fields about if the customer paid his taxes, the two tables is linked with autonumber from the main table.
I want always to keep them both with the same amount of records  (that means every customer has a record in the second table even if the second table has empty record with data only in the primary key field)
I need that cause with missing records I cannot run update query to auto fill the second table and i got an error of validation rule violation.
I use this sql:

```
update clients LEFT JOIN MonthlyTbl ON clients.SerialNo = MonthlyTbl.serialno
set sReport04='ready';
```

I have almost 700 records in the main table and only 80 records in the second, and when I run the sql it updates only 80!!!!
Thanks for Help

Comment: You should not use left join while updating

Comment: can you please make it clear which table contains 700 records & which contains 80?

Comment: the new table: monthlytbl contain 80 records, and the field sReport04 is in this table.

Comment: and I want the result to have monthly table with 700 records.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
update clients set sReport04='ready' where SerialNo in
(select serialno from MonthlyTbl);
```

Comment: If you mean this: "update MonthlyTbl set sReport04='ready' where SerialNo in
(select serialno from clients);"   the result will be only 80 records!!!  and I want to have MonthlyTbl with 700 records and the field with the primary key updated like the main table, and the the field sReport04 ='ready'.

Answer (score 0):

here is the right answer
first run the sql:

INSERT INTO monthlytbl ( serialno )
SELECT clients.serialno FROM clients
WHERE (((clients.[serialno]) Not In (select serialno from monthlytbl)));

and then:

select sreport04 from monthlytbl
set sReport04='ready';